# Different Levels of Magic Sensitivity?

Tags: harry-potter

A joke I made with a friend about Voldemort being a Sith Lord started me wondering about this.

In Star Wars, a person's sensitivity to the Force changes depending on their midichlorian count.  And then I remembered reading that some squibs in Harry Potter can cast some simple spells.

Are there different levels of sensitivity to magic in the magical world of Harry Potter?  I don't mean talent, I mean a different level of sensitivity to magic, which could lead to one person doing things another can't due to the innate sensitivity.  And if there are different levels of sensitivity, is there any idea what causes that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We see varying levels of sensitivity all over HP universe.

Neville is "almost a Squib", according to his own description - and a LOT of that has nothing to do with his personality. He really can't master certain magic "strength-wise" - such as Transfiguration. Yeah, he improved some spells in DA, but only to some extent.

If you notice, he's only effective against Death Eaters when he's using his real strengths - Herbology, or a reserve of bravery (he didn't magick away Nagini - he hacked her head off, Conan the Barbarian "I don't need no stinking magic, I have the strength of steel!" style)

Another example is Weasleys. Ron seems to have just as much brains as his family (see him playing wizard chess), yet he clearly has a lot worse magical skills compared to pretty much all his siblings.

However, there doesn't seem to be a clear canon distinction of "sensitivity" as you put it vs. "talent". I'm not quite sure what the distinction is in the first place, to be honest.